# htaccess - redirect from TLD to a subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all incoming traffic from TLD to a sub-folder. 
Example:

www.tld.com will be redirected to tld.com/1432/

Similarly:

tld.com -> tld.com/1432/

tld.com?page=2 -> tld.com/1432/?page=2

Essentially I'm storing all the script under /1432 and below. Nothing under root; except for the .htaccess.

Please tell me whether to save the .htaccess in root or in /1432.

index.php is in /1432.

Thanks. (I've copy pasted just about everything I found on the web to no avail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?tld\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^1432/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /1432/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. It doesn't work.
When you say 'document root' you mean /1432, right? So I did create tld.com/1432/.htaccess

Comment: Added tld.com/1432/.htaccess 
I doesn't have any effect at all. It's still showing tld.com/index.html. 

Then I tried putting it under tld's root, I get 'Internal Server Error'.

I'm wondering though, if it's put under /1432, how would it even get read at all? I would think the process begin at tld's root, found index.html (which is not the one it should render), then stops at that.

Comment: @10davvid it's supposed to go into your document root (e.g. where `/` goes).

Comment: @10davvid wait, I added a `/` where there shouldn't be one